How to map Mongoose populated models to generated GraphQL types in NestJS?
I'm using Typegoose with mongoose-autopopulate, and I'm trying to return a populated model inside my resolver. However, I get the error Ref<SomeReference> cannot be assigned to SomeReference>, _id, name is missing.....
Aside from making the reference field an object instead of ObjectID, are there any possible workaround/s for this? Thanks.
Code Snippets

Mongoose Models:
@plugin(autopopulate as any)
export class Collection extends TimeStamps {
  @prop()
  public name!: string;

  @prop({ autopopulate: true, ref: () => SomeReference })
  public link?: Ref<SomeReference>;
}

export class SomeReference extends TimeStamps {
  @prop()
  public name!: string;
}

GraphQL Schema (I'm using schema-first in NestJS):
type Collection {
    _id: ID!
    name: String!
    link: SomeReference
}

Resolver method:
private toPopulatedField(collection: CollectionDocument): Collection {
    return {
      _id: collection._id.toString(),
      name: collection.name,
      // link: {
      //   _id: collection.link._id.toString(),
      //   name: collection.link.name, --> error: name does not exist in ObjectID
      // },
    };
}


I dont know Graphql and what is required / possible, though some suggestions: if the value is required, you could error out if the field is not populated; you could also just not provide the value if it is optional; you could also defined something like ObjectId | SomeReference (i think graphql also calls this union types); you could also just make all fields other than _id optional (or use a nested object which is optional but the fields could be different).
